# Cannot invoke copyOf(char[], int) on the array type char[] in the function "public ArrayList<char[]> sort(ArrayList<char[]> chars)"

Tags: java

I'm coding a function that takes in an ArrayList, then copies each of the char[] into another char[] with added length, then the new char[] is added to a new ArrayList. The error occurs in the line when I try to copy the array. Am I incorrectly using the syntax or is my logic wrong?

```
public ArrayList<char[]> sort(ArrayList<char[]> chars)
{
  ArrayList<char[]> chars2 = new ArrayList<char[]>();
  for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++)
  {
    if (chars.get(i).length < chars.get(i + 1).length)
    {
      char[] c = chars.get(i).copyOf(chars.get(i), ((chars.get(i + 1).length - chars.get(i).length) + chars.get(i).length));
    }
  }
  return chars2;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? copyOf is a static method of Arrays. You need to call Arrays.copyOf

Comment: where you are adding updated `chars[]` to `chars2` list?

Comment: FYI: When you have a code that call `chars.get(i)` multiple time, you might want to think about use a temp variable to store the result.

Answer (score 2):

The object `char[]` does not have a `.copyOf` method. You can replace that with `Arrays.copyOf(array, size)`

```
int size = ((chars.get(i + 1).length - chars.get(i).length) + chars.get(i).length);
char[] c = Arrays.copyOf(chars.get(i), size);
```